# WPF : Wrap text while ScaleTransform is applied

Tags: c#, wpf, transformation, word-wrap

I want to apply ScaleTransform on a TextBlock while TextWrapping=Wrap.

This is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Border ClipToBounds="True"  Background="Beige" Width="200" Height="200">
        <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Text="AB CD EF GH IG KL MN OP QR ST UV WX YZ">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"  />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It works when ScaleX=1 , but it does not work when ScaleX>1.

Please look at these images :

[image: without ScaleX]

[image: with ScaleX]

I need both ScaleTransform and TextWrapping , How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`. Use the following code snippet to play around:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Slider x:Name="Scale" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Minimum="1" Maximum="20"/>
        <Border ClipToBounds="True" Background="Beige" Width="200" Height="200">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Text="AB CD EF GH IG KL MN OP QR ST UV WX YZ">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=Scale, Path=Value}"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

P.S. Use slider to adjust scaling and to see how scaling impacting the whole layout

Links: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_LayoutTransform)

Comment: Microsoft says: "LayoutTransform can lead to poor application performance ..."
. So, I do not want to use LayoutTransform because performance issue ,
 
But if I do not find a solution with RenderTransform for a few days,then I will accept your answer. Thank you